# How do I view variables values in nsight eclipse edition

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, nsight

I'm using nsight eclipse edition, and I cant figure out how to view variables values in debug mode for now (meaning usual variables in host memory, debugging usual c++ code so far). 
"Variables" tab does not contain anything useful for me (nothing I can use now at least), and Memory tab, which should be able to display variables by their addresses and also monitor expressions does not work for me either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using gcc 4.8, which caused problems. 
Now I downgraded to gcc 4.6 and it solved problem.

Robert Crovella, thanks for your effort.

Comment: For all in a hurry (and who need both gcc 4.6 and 4.8): 1) Install gcc-4.6, g++-4.6 2) In eclipse nsight: Project properties -> Build -> Settings -> NVCC Compiler -> Build Stages -> Compiler Path (-ccbin) = '/usr/bin/gcc-4.6' (Path to gcc-4.6)

Answer (score 1):

The following steps seemed to work for me:

- open nsight
- create a new project, select CUDA C/C++ project, and select CUDA Runtime project
- the project will be populated with a simple "bitreverse" code.  The initial configuration will be the debug configuration.  Select Project...Build Project to build the sample code (debug version).
- Now on the right hand side of the toolbar, press the "Debug" button, to switch to the Debug perspective.
- on the left of the first CUDA_CHECK_RETURN(...) line of code, right click and select "Toggle Breakpoint" to set a breakpoint at that line of code.
- select Run...Debug  The program will then be started in debug mode, stopped at the first line of code, and the host variables will be filled in in the upper right hand corner "Variables" pane.
- To the left of the `idata` variable, select the triangle to expand the sub-menu.  The submenu is populated with the values of `idata` at each index.  The data will be garbage, as it has not been initialized yet.
- Select Run...Resume to continue program execution.  Program execution will halted at the breakpoint previously set.
- If we inspect the `idata` variable in the "Variables" pane, we see that the values have been changed (initialized) to 0, 1, 2, ... etc.

If you attempt to debug a project for which you have built the "Release" configuration instead of "Debug" configuration, you will have a variety of issues, and will get a message "no source available" and there will be no variables displayed in the "Variables" pane.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the problem is that I'm unable to see local variables. I experimented a bit and found out that the Variables tab contains global variables only.

Comment: I think maybe what you mean is that you can only see variables that are currently in-scope.  If you want to view a specific variable, it needs to be in-scope.  So set a breakpoint in a section of the code where that variable is in-scope or being used, and you should then be able to inspect that variable.  If a variable is local to a function, and I step into or set a breakpoint in that function, I can then see any local variables in that function.

Comment: Nope, I wrote what I really meant. I can only see global variables.

Comment: So are you able to repeat the steps I have listed for a sample project, and for example see the `idata` variable (which is not a global variable)?

Comment: I'm able to repeat all steps, but, as I mentioned earlier, I don't see locals. 
I guess, it caused by my configuration. I'm using cuda 5.5 + gcc-4.8, for I need c++11 suppport.

Comment: Yes, I believe configuration of your system may be the issue.  gcc 4.8 is not an officially supported compiler, so it's possibly an issue, or some other aspect of your system configuration.